# Change the default language in Liferay

Tags: liferay

How to change the default for language?

When a user logs in for the first time, the default language is English, and I need to change that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change default language from Control panel - Portal Settings - Display Settings - Default langiuage.
Also you can override params at portal-ext.properties :

```
#
# Set the default locale used by Liferay. This locale is no longer set at
# the VM level. See LEP-2584.
#
user.country=US
user.language=en
```

BR,
Paul

Comment: "There's one caveat: If you've ever set this configuration through the
UI (in ControlPanel -> Portal Settings -> Display Settings), they will be stored in the database and override what you configure in
 portal-ext.properties. Thus, you might want to check what you find in
 Control Panel and might need to configure there instead of
 portal-ext.properties.

Source: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/45421596

Answer (score 4):

From Liferay 7 (released in 2016), the default language setting can be found in the UI at:

**Control Panel** > **Instance Settings** > **Miscellaneous** > **Display Settings**

[image]

Don't forget to press "Save" at the bottom of the page.

As MDT said, it overrides whatever is in `portal-ext.properties`.